# Detect click-outside for multiple alert boxes in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been working on multiple alert boxes components with the click-outside directive. For a single component works fine, but for many components it has been nightmarish. I have created an example so someone could please help me with this problem.

1.When a button is clicked the alert box opens, click out side it closes. this is fine...

2.When a button is clicked the alert box opens, then another button is clicked another alert box opens, but the first one doesn't close, which is wrong it should close.

Here is the example I created https://jsfiddle.net/Xarina/evs98tfo/108/

Vue code looks like this

```
Vue.component('alerts-boxes', {
template: '#alerts-boxes-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      alertsBoxes: [
        { label:'button 1', content:'Vue.js: The Basics' },
        { label:'button 2', content:'Vue.js Components' },
        { label:'button 3', content:'Server Side Rendering with Vue' },
      ]
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('buttons', {
  template: '#buttons-template',
  props: {label: String, content: String},
    data() {
    return {
            isShowing: false
    }
  },
  directives: {
     'click-outside': {
       bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
         el.event = function(event) {
           if (!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
             vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
           }
         };
         el.addEventListener('click', el.stopProp);
         document.body.addEventListener('click', el.event);
       },
       unbind: function(el) {
         el.removeEventListener('click', el.stopProp);
         document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.event);
       },
       stopProp(event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
       }
      }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleEvent: function () {
        this.isShowing = !this.isShowing; 
    },
    closeEvent() {
      this.isShowing = false;
    },
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the buttons ignore `click outsude` events since they have `.stop` modifier. So, you have to manually set `isShowing = false` for the other items on click:

```html
<buttons 
  :items="alertsBoxes" 
  :item="alertBox" 
  :label="alertBox.label" 
  :content="alertBox.content"
></buttons>
```

```js
props: { items: Array, item: Object, label: String, content: String}
...
toggleEvent: function () {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id !== this.item.id) {
      item.isShowing = false
    }
  })
  this.item.isShowing = !this.item.isShowing; 
}
```

I modified your objects and set each of them `isShowing` property.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a93yz2fb/1/

Comment: @MariaZ glad I could help :)

Comment: thank you again, today I implemented this idea was brilliant!!!, I thought so much of a possible solution, and I was so confused... this helped me understand some stuff